# Android, Fresco Gif displaying in recyclerview, with start and stop "onClick"

Tags: android, fresco

I'm trying to achieve something like 9gag, where you have a list of gifs inside a recyclerview and you can start&stop each of them within a click on the image.

I can implement such feature on my own, but i was wondering if any of the current image loaders libraries (especially Fresco) has this feature built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Fresco allows [manual control of animations](http://frescolib.org/docs/animations.html). The simplest way is this:

```
Animatable animatable = mSimpleDraweeView.getController().getAnimatable();
if (animatable != null) {
  animatable.start();
  // later
  animatable.stop();
}
```